# Symbolic variables automatically update in theano

Tags: python, logistic-regression, theano

Im following the theano tutorial given [here](http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/logreg.html) for simple Stochastic Gradient Descent. Here however I am unable to understand in this block how the values of `p_y_given_x` and `y_pred` are getting automatically updated according to the values of `W` and `b` since later down when we run test_logistic() we are only updating the values of `W` and `b`? 
Thanks

```
class LogisticRegression(object):

    def __init__(self, input, n_in, n_out):
        self.W = theano.shared(
            value=numpy.zeros(
                (n_in, n_out),
                dtype=theano.config.floatX
            ),
            name='W',
            borrow=True
        )
        # initialize the baises b as a vector of n_out 0s
        self.b = theano.shared(
            value=numpy.zeros(
                (n_out,),
                dtype=theano.config.floatX
            ),
            name='b',
            borrow=True
        )
        self.p_y_given_x = T.nnet.softmax(T.dot(input, self.W) + self.b)
        self.y_pred = T.argmax(self.p_y_given_x, axis=1)
        self.params = [self.W, self.b]

    def negative_log_likelihood(self, y):
        return -T.mean(T.log(self.p_y_given_x)[T.arange(y.shape[0]), y])
        # end-snippet-2

    def errors(self, y):
        if y.ndim != self.y_pred.ndim:
            raise TypeError(
                'y should have the same shape as self.y_pred',
                ('y', y.type, 'y_pred', self.y_pred.type)
            )
        # check if y is of the correct datatype
        if y.dtype.startswith('int'):
            # the T.neq operator returns a vector of 0s and 1s, where 1
            # represents a mistake in prediction
            return T.mean(T.neq(self.y_pred, y))
        else:
            raise NotImplementedError()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`p_y_given_x` and `y_pred` are symbolic variable (just python object from Theano). Those python variable that point to the Theano object do not get updated. They just represent the computation we want to do. Think like in pseudo-code.

They will be used when compiling the Theano function. It is only then that the value will be computed. But this do not cause any change to the python variable that point to the object `p_y_given_x` and `y_pred`. The object are not changed.

Understanding this distinction take time for some people. It is a new way of thinking. So don't hesitate to ask questions. One thing that help is to always ask yourself if you are in the symbolic world or the numerical world. the numerical world happen only with compiled Theano function.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused, agreed its all working in terms of pseudocode, however how does updating the shared variables self.W and self.b automatically result in updation of the values denoted by symbolic variables derived from these shared variables?

Comment: Theano keep trac of that. When you call theano.function(), we just keep a reference to the "container" where the value is. The "container" is just something internal in Theano you do not need to know(just a normal python class that wrap the value). It just easily allow us to have the compiled function and the shared variable have access to the same underlying data. The function and the shared variable have a reference to the same container. So both see the same value at all time.

Comment: Thanks! So I conclude that every tensor variable that has been computed using a shared variable will automatically update as soon as the corresponding shared variable value is updated.